# Changing the background color in HTML with a Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, stylesheet

I have some Javascript Variables which i want to give to my HTML stylesheet:
For Example my Variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var color="#2E2E2E";
</script>
```

Now I want to give this variable to one of my stylesheets. For Example:

```
<div style="background:color">this is a test</tes>
```

I am a real nooby and I am only doing one little project. I only know a little html. Can someone please explain me how it works? I found a lot in the net but don't know how to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the element in your JS somehow. For example:

```
document.querySelector('div')
```

Then set its color, maybe like this:

```
document.querySelector('div').style.color = color;
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBD2g/) for a demo.

Comment: That is working fine but the changing of the backgroundcolor only works with firefox:
'document.getElementById('logo_home').style="background-color:"+color_home;'
but other things like adding a picture or changin the width are working. Why ?

Comment: Because you are using wrong. This is correct: `document.getElementById('logo_home').style.backgroundColor = color_home;`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change that element's color or something with JS, you need to use ID. Like

```
<div id="something" style="background:color">this is a test</div>
```

Than you cane use this JS scrypt:

```
document.getElementById('something').style="background-color:"+color; // where color is a variable with an color, like #354268 or #E3A or red.
```